# How to vertically center and align everything else after that with HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align the first **div** at the center of the browser and everything below it below that **div**.

I may be able to wrap these two divs in another **div** and *centering* that div may work, but I can't change this html structure and have to achieve with two divs only. The first div is a dynamic container where different html will be displayed. The second div is static.

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  I'm at the center of the Browser!
</div>
<div>I'm just below the center!</div>
```

Comment: according to fact that your `.center` div take whole space, its technically centered...

Comment: I just updated that it is **vertically centering** and not horizontally centering.

Comment: do you have given height of `.center` div or is that flexible?

Comment: There is no given height because the browser can be running from iPad or desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser supports viewport units, you can use this way:

```
.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin-top:50vh;  
}
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/fgpqkrr4/

Answer (score 2):

Add width and margin: auto 0 to the css class and apply it to the div elements.

like this:

```
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}


<div class="center">
  I'm at the center of the Browser!
</div>
<div class="center">I'm just below the center!</div>
```

Comment: The width can't be set because the browser can be running from iPad or desktop.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (I added the color only to make it easier to see the result)

```css
.center {
 width:750px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color:Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  I'm at the center of the Browser!
</div>
<div>I'm just below the center!</div>
```

Comment: it should be vertical centered, not horizontal

Comment: @Pepo_rasta ups my bad...haven't seen that.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary:**
You can use this code that is in [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eugm24z/).

---

I wrote two classes named `.center-x` and `.center-y`. You can use these classes when you want to center elements by x and y axes.

The code:

```css
.box-1 {
    background: #00adef;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.box-2 {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 170px;
}

.center-y {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform:  translateX(-50%);
}

.center-x.center-y {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1 center-y center-x">
  I'm at the center of the Browser!
    
  <div class="box-2 center-x">I'm just below the center!</div>
</div>
```

And if you want to center by vertical, just remove the `.center-x` class from `.box-1`. Else if you want to center by horizontal, just remove the `.center-x` class from `.box-1`.